# Why does my Windows Service automatically quit after approx 5 secs?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I've create a Windows Service using C# that when OnStart is called creates a new thread from another class. This new thread then loops waiting for any incoming TCP connections. Or it should. When I start the service it automatically stops after about 5 seconds. I don't know why it is doing this. I understand that services close on their own if they have no work to do but the work has been specified for it. Anyone got any ideas why this would be happening? My OnStart Method looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new StateMachine().AcceptConnections);
        thread.Start();      
    }
```

Which then calls this method:

```
        Int32 port = 13000;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

        // Start listening for client requests.
        server.Start();
        // Enter the listening loop.
        do
        {
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            ReceivedData();                
        } while (true);
    }
```

It does not stay on long enough to allow any clients to connect to the TcpListner.

Help?

Comment: My guess would be that an exception crashes the service. Try adding logging to the AcceptConnections method, to see where it hangs.

Comment: I agree with SWeko. Either add some logging, or move the "this method" code into a stand-alone console application to try to get a better idea of what it's doing or not doing.

Comment: Probably being denied network access?

Comment: @Marc - wouldn't network access to '127.0.0.1' be a gimme? Unless port is already in use.

Comment: The Windows event log probably has something to say about it.

Comment: This being a Service. you should have both Logging and Exception handling in place. And then you wouldn't have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, are you sure you want your service to spawn a new thread to do this?  You can't simply do it on the main thread?

To debug your problem, do one or both of the following:

1. Add some logging, either using the EventLog or a logging framework (Log4Net).
2. [Run your service as a console app](https://jacopretorius.net/2009/08/running-a-windows-service-inside-a-console-application.html) and debug it in Visual Studio

Comment: I ran it as a console app and it stops when I create the server i.e. server = new TcpListener(localAddr,port).

How do I create or add to the EventLogs, it is already set to autolog = false, but whenever I try to call EventLog.WriteEntry it says that the service started and then stopped suddenly. I'm stuck.

Comment: So did you put a breakpoint on that line?  What happens when you step into the code?  Try and put a try-catch block around the code that you think is causing the issue to try and see if any exceptions occur.  Check this MSDN article to see how to write to the eventlog - it's very easy.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024

Comment: Hmm, I have got it down to a configuration error. I removeed the app.config file I have created and it seems to be working for now. I think I have either referenced or created the app.config file incorrectly. Thanks for all your help though!

Comment: `Firstly, are you sure you want your service to spawn a new thread to do this? You can't simply do it on the main thread?` - no, they absolutely cannot do that. Windows service has about 30 seconds to exit from OnStart, or risk being killed by the ServiceManager. That it standard windows behavior and applies to any OnXxxx service management callbacks. And I suppose they want their TCP listeners live longer than 30 seconds. This asnwer should not be 'accepted' as long as it still contains that suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you app code runs OK when not set up as a service.  If your code runs OK when not set up as a service, my guess is that your `OnStart` is taking too long for some reason.  If you cannot speed it up, the info here allows you to handle necessary startup latency.

In Win32, you have to update the [service status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus.aspx) by notifying the Service Control Manager (SCM) of startup (and stop) progress periodically, or it will think your service is hung and kill it.  You may need to do this only once, or on a timer if your initialization takes a long time.  While your startup (stop) logic is in progress, you tell SCM you are in state START_PENDING (STOP_PENDING) and once it's done you tell it you are in STARTED (STOPPED) state.

In the managed world, this goal is achieved by calling [ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx).  There is a thorough overview of this topic [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2009/02/19/in-depth-how-net-managed-services-interact-with-the-servicecontrolmanager-scm-kim-hamilton.aspx).  The money quote:

> This is where your managed service
>   needs to pay attention to avoid the
>   SCM flagging your service as
>   unresponsive.
>
> - You don’t have to explicitly update
>     the state; ServiceBase does this for
>     you when your OnStart or OnStop method
>     completes
> - You do have to call
>     RequestAdditionalTime if you expect
>     the OnX method to exceed the timeout.

Comment: The app is working fine when it is a standalone console app, both the client and the server can connect and interact. I added in a try catch on the acceptconnections method and it must be catching an exception because the service doesnt stop anymore but I still can't connect to the server with the client. I assume this is because it caught the exception and hasn't actually created the server so therefore the client has nothing to connect to.

Comment: I am wanting to the acceptconnections method to run forever to recieve any new incoming connections through Tcp. I'm beginning to think that this might not be possible as the SCM will think, as you said, that my app has died and will kill it. Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: @stuartmclark - follow earlier suggestions and get the exception output to a log file or the Event Viewer.  Having your code run forever is fine (that's what services as are supposed to do) so long as SCM interaction time in `OnStart` and siblings is managed per my response.  Does not sound like that is your issue at this point though - just a socket failure? Diags will show you for sure, and you will need this to support your code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Right I've got it. I was doing something stupid with the config file, which including moving the .exeXML config file to the wrong place. Which resulted in an Configuration Error, and the service wasn't liking it. I've got it up and running now though. So thanks for your help.